# Filter value of object in VueJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuejs2

I need to check if the **value** of **startAt** is present in an object. It should return the **id** of that object if it's in it.

Object:

```js
[{
  "id": "1234567",
  "createTimestamp": "2020",
  "name": {
    "action": "",
    "allDay": false,
    "category": "Misc",
    "startAt": "05",
    "title": "foo"
  },
  "updateTimestamp": "2020"
}]
```

Below is what I have so far. The filtering works but I can't access the **id** to return it.

```html
<div v-for="(hour, i) in 24" :key="i">
  {{ filterByHour(hour) }}
</div>
```

```js
filterByHour(id) {
  if (id < 10) {
    id = 0 + id
  }

  const result = this.events.filter(item => item.name.startAt === id.toString())
  return result
}
```

How to return the **id** of the object?

Comment: And the problem is? `result` is an array. If it isn't empty return the id of the only (if the input is really only an array with one element) element in it.

Comment: What you are getting for `result`,  You are not returning inside filter?

Comment: @RishiRaut OP is using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) which has an implicit `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think the problem is in `id = 0 + id`. When id is 5 this line evaluates to `5` only not `05`. Change to `id = '0' + id`, which will convert to string.
2. After the `filter`, use the `map` to extract id.

```js
const events = [
  {
    id: "1234567",
    createTimestamp: "2020",
    name: {
      action: "",
      allDay: false,
      category: "Misc",
      startAt: "05",
      title: "foo"
    },
    updateTimestamp: "2020"
  }
];

function filterByHour(id) {
  if (id < 10) {
    id = "0" + id;
  }

  const result = events
    .filter(item => item.name.startAt === String(id))
    .map(x => x.id);
  return result;
}

console.log(filterByHour(5));
console.log(filterByHour(11));
console.log(filterByHour());
```